# Why does the xml value() method handle variables differently when executing a dynamically built string vs injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm perplexed as to why these 2 executions give different results.

Say I have the below XML:

```
<Main>
    <job id="1">
        <Action>true</Action>
    </job>
    <job id="2">
        <Action>false</Action>
    </job>
</Main>
```

The below SQL will give a `null` for actionvalue (I got the syntax from example A [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)):

```
exec sp_executesql
N'
select 
    j.value(''(job[@id="@jobid"])[1]/Action[1]'',''varchar(max)'') as actionvalue
from dbo.xmlstuff
    cross apply content.nodes(''/Main'') a(j)
N'@jobid varchar(1)',
@jobid = '1'
```

While the below gives the actual value (in this case `true`) (I got this syntax from [here](https://www.databasejournal.com/ms-sql/executing-dynamic-sql-using-sp-executesql/)):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(500),
    @jobid varchar(1) = '1'
        
set @sql = 
'
select 
    j.value(''(job[@id="' + @jobid + '"])[1]/Action[1]'',''varchar(max)'') as actionvalue
from dbo.xmlstuff
    cross apply content.nodes(''/Main'') a(j)

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@jobid varchar(1)', @jobid=@jobid;
```

**Why is that?** It obviously has something to do with how dynamically built string executions work vs how injection executions work, but the above 2 queries seem like they should accomplish the same thing.

I tried making jobid int and varchar with the same result. I also tried using more variables in the top query, and they work just fine. It's just the piece within the square brackets after `job` that seems to have a problem with using variables.

Comment: That second statement isnt using parameterisation, it's using **injection**.

Comment: Your first example returns `null` because it is literally looking for the element `<job id="@jobid">`. There's no need to use `sp_executesql` and/or dynamic SQL here. Have you read up on the [sql:variable() XQuery extension function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) yet? Integrating that knowledge your value extraction becomes `j.value('(job[@id=sql:variable("@jobid")])[1]/Action[1]','varchar(max)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They act differently because they aren't the same. Your first attempt passes a variable's name in quotes, meaning it is inferred as the *literal value* `"@jobid"` *not* the value of that parameter.

The latter attempt used injection, and thus *injects* a `1` into the string. You could remove the 2 latter parameters from the call to `sys.sp_executesql` in that attempt and it would still work.

You, however, don't need dynamic SQL here. Instead tell XQuery that you are passing it a variable and the execution works:

```sql
declare @xml xml = '<Main>
    <job id="1">
        <Action>true</Action>
    </job>
    <job id="2">
        <Action>false</Action>
    </job>
</Main>';

declare @jobid char(1) = '1';

select 
    j.value('(job[@id=sql:variable("@jobid")])[1]/Action[1]','varchar(max)') as actionvalue
from (values(@xml)) X (content)
    cross apply content.nodes('/Main') a(j);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AISlh-Gg)

Comment: Good answer. `(job[@id=sql:variable("@jobid")])/Action/text())[1]` is probably a bit faster though

Comment: I had literally copied the OP's in truth, and was typing on a phone; the casing would be *way" different if I'd of had the time.